# Meteor with both blaze (web) and angular (mobile)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova

I'd like to create a mobile/cordova version of my Meteor web application.  The web version uses blaze -- which I'd like to stick with -- and for the mobile app version [Ionic](http://ionicframework.com/) seems like an excellent choice for UX.  Ionic is more-or-less coupled with Angular which creates a templating conflict at runtime:

```
error: conflict: two packages included in the app (angular-templates and templating) are both trying to handle *.html
error: conflict: two packages included in the app (pbastowski:angular-babel and ecmascript) are both trying to handle *.js
```

Other than, say, forking my project to create a separate non-blaze repo, are there any ways to configure meteor to only use angular/babel if the app is running with cordova?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a good bit of digging and research, this is what I've come to conclude:

It seems the typical solution to this kind of problem in Meteor is to disaggregate your application into a collection of packages.

With packages there is a greater control over how and where dependencies are loaded.  So in this particular case, there'd be at least two packages -- one which contains browser specific code and another which contains Cordova specific code.

Here's one simple example of an application broken into packages supporting a mobile and web-based experiences: https://github.com/Compy/meteor-mobile-desktop

And here's a pretty comprehensive tutorial on breaking an existing application into a package based architecture: http://experimentsinmeteor.com/package-based-architecture/